# Where can I ask a question about employment?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would have thought careers.stackoverflow.com would have been the place, but I don't see a forum.

I have a question about advancing career positions in IT.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposal in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) named [IT Careers & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers-training); but it's in definition phase at the moment. It is a proposed Q&A site for IT Professionals or budding IT Professionals who want advice into how to develop and progress their career. You can follow it and hope it passes to beta phase soon.

Answer (score 0):

For me, [I asked my question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/169501/how-to-enter-the-field-with-0-experience-and-a-a-cert), since thats where all the IT people hang out. However I would highly recommend [searching existing questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/career-development) before asking your own. I only asked mine because it was very specific and not covered by any other question.

Do note that officially ServerFault is not for career help.